# Why does the VBA Main form close by Sub Form's 'x' close button event?

Tags: excel, vba

Hey so I am working on some forms in VBA and am having some issues. I open other forms from my main form, but when I exit one of the other forms using the red "x" button, it closes my main form as well, not just the other form.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a code that only closes the sub form.

e.g. your sub form name is SubForm1

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "SubForm1"
```

But since you are using x-button to close the sub form, you can use `QueryClose` Event.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
     Cancel = True
    End if
End Sub
```

PS: helpful if you could post your code by editing your question.

Comment: I havent done any code for the "x" button, only the actual button i put in has code to close the form. basically i have a button called "close" on the form and it closes that form only. the "x" button is just there on the form by default. i want to only close THIS form if that red button is clicked, whereas currently it closes all open forms

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but check the setting of the forms "Showmodal" property fixed it for me.